# R shiny - I created a dataframe within "Renderplot" and would like to access it outside of this. How can I make it reactive?

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

I have created a data frame inside a render plot function and have plotted this. I would like to access the last value of the column "fund" in this data frame and insert it into an info box. In the code attached the value of fund is not reactive in my info box.

I have tried simply taking the lump of code that generates the data frame and inserting it into a reactive function and recalling it in the info box and renderplot fuction but could then get neither to work. Is it possible to create a reactive data frame? If so, can I just access one value from the data frame? I'm pretty new to all of this so I apologise if the following code is messy.

```
server <- function(input, output) {
  output$line <- renderPlot({
    intrate <- input$int/100    #where I created the data frame
    fund <- as.numeric()
    return <- as.numeric()
    draw <- as.numeric()
    fund[1] <- input$pot
    draw[1] <- input$dd
    age <- c(input$age:94)
    for(i in 1:(95-input$age)){
      draw[i+1] <- draw[i]*(1+input$inf/100)
      return[i] <- fund[i]*intrate
      fund[i+1] <- max(0,fund[i] + return[i] - draw[i]) 
    }
    draw <- head(draw, -1)
    fund<- head(fund,-1)
    data <- as.data.frame(cbind(age, fund, draw, return))
    

#my plot
    ggplot(data = data, mapping = aes(age, fund)) +
      geom_line(color="red", size=1, alpha=0.9, linetype=1) +
      scale_y_continuous(labels = function(x) format(x, scientific = FALSE), limits = c(0,NA))+
      labs(y = "Fund (€)", x = "Age (Years)")+
      theme_light()
  })
  
  output$fad <- renderInfoBox(       ##where I want to access fund for an infobox
    
    infoBox(title = "Fund at Death", paste0(round(tail(fund, n=1),2)), icon = icon("credit-card"),
            color = "blue")
  )
  
}
```

To give context, I am creating a pension drawdown calculator where the retirement age is an input and death is assumed at age 95.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this should work:

```
server <- function(input, output) {
  data <- reactive({
    intrate <- input$int/100    #where I created the data frame
    fund <- as.numeric()
    return <- as.numeric()
    draw <- as.numeric()
    fund[1] <- input$pot
    draw[1] <- input$dd
    age <- c(input$age:94)
    for(i in 1:(95-input$age)){
      draw[i+1] <- draw[i]*(1+input$inf/100)
      return[i] <- fund[i]*intrate
      fund[i+1] <- max(0,fund[i] + return[i] - draw[i]) 
    }
    draw <- head(draw, -1)
    fund<- head(fund,-1)
    data <- as.data.frame(cbind(age, fund, draw, return))
  })

  output$line <- renderPlot({
  #my plot
    ggplot(data = data(), mapping = aes(age, fund)) +
      geom_line(color="red", size=1, alpha=0.9, linetype=1) +
      scale_y_continuous(labels = function(x) format(x, scientific = FALSE), limits = c(0,NA))+
      labs(y = "Fund (€)", x = "Age (Years)")+
      theme_light()
  })
  
  output$fad <- renderInfoBox(       ##where I want to access fund for an infobox
    
    infoBox(title = "Fund at Death", paste0(round(tail(fund, n=1),2)), icon = icon("credit-card"),
            color = "blue")
  )
  
}
```

To summarize: You put the data.frame part in a reactive expression and we call that into the plot by referring to data()